# Connecting to Appharbor database from Xamarin Portable

Tags: xamarin, remote-access, appharbor

I am new to Xamarin and I recently have an assignment that I need to access to a remote database through Xamarin Portable. I have an Appharbor database, and I heard that WCF will do the job. Any guidance to achieve that?

*It also needs the ability to alter the content of database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is what database you use MSSQL ? At most databases you need something between the database and the App like WCF.

But today mostly used are Web API's for that thing. You can learn more about it here http://www.asp.net/web-api

Comment: I think then one of the easiest ways would be a combination of asp.net web api and httpclient. HttpClient to consume the Web API within the PCL

Comment: Thanks! Will try it out now.